# Union-find disjoint set solution to calculating sizes of connected components

Tags: python, graph, union-find

I'm given a distance and a list of points in a plane, where I have to return a sorted list of the size of each connected component where each edge is shorter or equal to the distance threshold.

I've implemented a union-find disjoint set as a solution:

```py
import array
from collections import Counter

class DisjointSet:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.parent = array.array('I', range(self.n))
        self.rank = array.array('I', [0] * self.n)

    def sizes_of_unique_sets(self):
        count = Counter(self.find(i) for i in range(self.n))
        return list(count.values()) 

    def find(self, a):
        if self.parent[a] != a:
            self.parent[a] = self.find(self.parent[a])
        return self.parent[a]

    def union(self, a, b):
        a_root = self.find(a)
        b_root = self.find(b)
        if a_root == b_root:
            return

        if self.rank[a_root] > self.rank[b_root]:
            self.parent[b_root] = a_root
        elif self.rank[a_root] < self.rank[b_root]:
            self.parent[a_root] = b_root
        else:
            self.parent[b_root] = a_root
            self.rank[a_root] += 1
```

To compute the solution, I iterate the list of points twice (the second loop starts from the first index + 1)

```py
def disjoint_set_compute(distance, points):
    N = len(points)
    disjoint_set = DisjointSet(N)

    for i in range(N - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, N):
            if points[i].inside_ball(points[j], distance) and disjoint_set.find(i) != disjoint_set.find(j):
                disjoint_set.union(i, j)

    res = sorted(disjoint_set.sizes_of_unique_sets(), reverse=True)
    return res
```

When benchmarked, I get 5 seconds from 1,000 points on 6 virtual cores, which is kind of sad, but it's even worse that I can't find a way to further optimise it, other than using a spatial data structure like a Quadtree or KD-tree, which I will work on further. I can also try a BFS approach.

Is there any way to improve this current implementation?

Answer (score 1):

## lint

```
    N = len(points)
```

[Pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
asks that you assign to downcased `n`, please.

---

## verb

```
                disjoint_set.union(i, j)
```

Hmmm, that's slightly odd.
It's clear we're evaluating for side effects.
It doesn't seem to fit in with the familiar
[union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union)
operator in standard library,
which produces a *new* result object.

Consider a more explicit name that is clearly a verb,
perhaps `.add_to_union`.

---

## docstrings

The `DisjointSet` class really deserves a """docstring""",
even if it's just a
[wiki ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets).
And the `parent` and `rank` datastructures need a little love,
in the class docstring or even just as a `# comment`.

It's clear what `sizes_of_unique_sets` does,
but a docstring really ought to explain it
so caller knows what return value to expect without examining the code.

It turns out that `find` and `union` deserve docstrings, too.

There's probably something you'd like to say about
[big-Oh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)
time complexity of selected operations, such as `union`.

---

## recursion

```
        if self.parent[a] != a:
            self.parent[a] = self.find(self.parent[a])
```

In many ways this is beautiful.

But consider either

1. coding this in iterative fashion, or
2. documenting how `n` and `sys.getrecursionlimit()` are related

Even if this was implemented in Scheme there's no opportunity for
[TCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).
Large datastructures will trigger RecursionError,
essentially a stack overflow.

I am perfectly fine with the fact that `.find` has
side effects. But that should be mentioned in the
docstring, as simple inspection of the signature
would suggest it is readonly.

---

## invariants

What is always true about `parent` ?
And about `rank` ?
Write them down.

In the course of writing them down,
you might possibly find that the definition is inconvenient,
and you prefer to do all the mutating within `.union`,
rather than handing some of the responsibility to `.find`.

*Do* cite the references that inspired your
choice of datastructure and of algorithm.

---

## speed

> 5 seconds from 1,000 points on 6 virtual cores

It's unclear why VCPU > 1 would be relevant, since there's just one
[GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

Consider coding some of this library in a language like Rust
if you want `.union` to go faster.
Though even in that case, it would still seem like there's
very little opportunity to spin up worker threads and
get anything useful done with them,
unlike e.g. numpy finding the
[inverse](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html)
of a large matrix.

Adding [numba](https://pypi.org/project/numba)
`@jit` decorators would be pretty low effort.
You have already adopted a sensible array datastructure
(rather than the cache misses of chasing `list` object pointers),
so that's good.

*Do* consider sending your (x, y) coords to a
relational database that has *already* implemented
spatial indexes for you.
I have had excellent results with radius-based queries against
[PostGIS](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html)
via [sqlalchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core).
For large number of points,
using appropriate datastructure really makes a huge difference.
There's just no comparison between having pair of x- and y-indexes
versus a combined spatial xy-index.

I love sqlite but have never used its spatial
[R-tree](https://sqlite.org/rtree.html#creating_an_r_tree_index),
nor the [SpatiaLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpatiaLite)
extension. It would be thirty minutes well invested to try them out.

---

This class achieves many of its design goals.
Some documentation deficiencies really ought to be
addressed prior to merging down to `main`.
Given that, I would be happy to delegate or accept
maintenance tasks on this codebase.

Answer (score 1):

> I get 5 seconds from 1,000 points

There are about n²/2 `inside_ball` queries and possibly a similar number of union/find operations. So, 10 microseconds per pair, on average. For a language that isn't Python that would be a lot, but for Python it does not sound too outrageous to me.

This in your code:

> ```
> disjoint_set.find(i) != disjoint_set.find(j)
> ```

Is redundant, `union` does that anyway. But it should not have a large impact. Calling `find` here makes, thanks to path compression, the `find` inside `union` cheap. Either way the real work is done *somewhere*, but only once, and the only thing that may change is the amount of overhead.

A `DisjointSet` based on a couple of arrays of integers is good, perhaps some details could be slightly improved.

`find` does not need to be recursive (which walks the path twice, once up and then back down), that is an obvious way to do it, but there are alternatives. The "classic" one is still a two-pass algorithm: find the ultimate parent (iteratively), then walk back up and update everyones parent. As [noted on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), there are one-pass iterative alternatives, path splitting and path halving. I don't know how good they are, but you can try them. They walk the path only once, but the trade-off is that they do less path compression.

It is quite easy to keep track of how many disjoint components are left, if you find that you regularly get down to only 1 component, it may be useful to detect that case and early-exit.